# how can I tell what view this controller will return?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4 and learning an MVC 4 codebase. In the music store tutorial from Microsoft, I added views by right clicking a method in a controller and choosing Add View.

This allowed me to know what view was linked with what controller.

But in the codebase, there is a file called `homecontroller.cs` w/ a method called "index" that returns a view. How can I tell what view the method returns?

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(bool preserveShowFor = false)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("..."))
        {
            return View(new HomeViewModel...); //how do I know what view this returns?
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, MVC will look for a view with the same name as the action result, in this case, Index

You could specify it manually by returning this instead

```
new View("MyViewName", new HomeViewModel())
```

Answer (score 2):

The view your code will return is the Index one. The view is in a subfolder called Home.

If no view is specified then the view with the same name as the action is returned.

Comment: This is partially true. If it does not find a view named Index.aspx or Index.cshtml (depending on installed view engines) in the Views/Home folder it will then search the Views/Shared folder for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

In this case it will look for a view called Index to match the method name... ASP.Net MVC supports a lot of conventions such as this, but you can code things explicitly if you really want to...

Answer (score 0):

Right click inside the method and click 'Go To View'. It should be in a folder under views  called Home.

You can also pass explicit views

Answer (score 0):

The convention is that it will check the folder under Views that has the same name as your controller, with the name of your action.

So in this case, Views/Home/Index.aspx